# Do ASP.NET developers really need to be concerned with thread safety?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I consider myself aware of the concepts of threading and why certain code is or isn’t “thread-safe,” but as someone who primarily works with ASP.NET, threading and thread safety is something I rarely think about. However, I seem to run across numerous comments and answers (not necessarily for ASP.NET) on Stack Overflow to the effect of “***warning – that’s not thread-safe!***,” and it tends to make me second guess whether I’ve written similar code that actually could cause a problem in my applications. [shock, horror, etc.]  So I’m compelled to ask:

**Do ASP.NET developers *really* need to be concerned with thread safety?**

My Take: While a web application is inherently multi-threaded, each particular request comes in on a single thread, and all *non-static* types you create, modify, or destroy are exclusive to that single thread/request. If the request creates an instance of a DAL object which creates an instance of a business object and [I want to lazy-initialize a collection within this object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350502/initialize-a-collection-within-an-object/350585#350585), *it doesn’t matter* if it’s not thread-safe, because it will never be touched by another thread. ...Right? (Let’s assume I’m not starting a new thread to kick off a long-running asynchronous process during the request. I’m well aware that changes everything.)

Of course, static classes, methods and variables are just the opposite. They are shared by *every* request, and the developer must be very careful not to have “unsafe” code that when executed by one user, can have an unintended effect on all others.

But that’s about it, and thus thread safety in ASP.NET mostly boils down to this: Be careful how you design and use statics. Other than that, you don’t need to worry about it much at all.

Am I wrong about any of this? Do you disagree? Enlighten me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are certain objects in addition to static items that are shared across all requests to an application.  Be careful about putting items in the application cache that are not thread-safe, for example.  Also, nothing prevents you from spawning your own threads for background processing while handling a request.

Comment: Don't forget session values. :)

Comment: At which point session values will be accessed by more than one thread?

Comment: @Randolpho Session values are always immutable strings which point to the user active session, can you think of a time where one thread can adjust the value of a session string and make another thread get the wrong value? Not trying to be a smart a*s but I can't think of a way this would hurt anything

Answer (score 5):

There are different levels of ASP.NET Developers. You could make a perfectly fine career as an ASP.NET Developer without knowing anything threads, mutexes, locks, semaphores and even design patterns because a high percentage of ASP.NET applications are basically CRUD applications with little to no additional business logic.

However, most great ASP.NET Developers which I have come across aren't just ASP.NET Developers, their skills run the gamut so they know all about threading and other good stuff because they don't limit themselves to ASP.NET.

So no, for the most part ASP.NET Developers do not need to know about thread safety. But what fun is there in only knowing the bare minimum?

Comment: I like that you pointed this out - I agree, and didn't mean to suggest that the developer as a person should not learn the nuances of threading. It's just that I keep running across the "not thread-safe!!" warning messages so often, it's a little distracting when it may not really a concern for most ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you covered it all very well. I agree with you. Being focused on ASP.NET only it rarely (if at all) comes to multi-threading issues.

The situation changes however when it comes to optimizations. Whenever your start a long-lasting query, you may often want to let it run in a separate thread so that the page load does not stop until the server reports connection timeout. You may wish to have this page periodically check for completion status to notify the user. Here where it comes to multi-threading issues.

Answer (score 3):

Only if you create, within the processing stream for a single HTTPRequest, multiple threads of your own... For e.g., if the web page will display stock quotes for a set of stocks, and you make separate calls to a stock quote service, on independant threads, to retrive the quotes, before generating the page to send back to the client... Then you would have to make sure that the code you are running in *your* threads is thread-safe.