# Single instance of IOrganizationService for microsoft dynamics crm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

i am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM in Web API project,
currently i am creating new instance of IOrganizationService on every new request,

my question is, What if i create single static instance of IOrganizationService in Global.asax's Application_Start() method and use it for each request, is it good or bad ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The IOrganizationService is not thread safe.  Putting it in a static variable in an ASP.NET web app without addressing the thread safety is probably a bad idea, for this reason alone.

[Do ASP.NET developers really need to be concerned with thread safety?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341827/do-asp-net-developers-really-need-to-be-concerned-with-thread-safety)

The [XrmLibrary](http://xrmlibrary.codeplex.com/) includes a thread safe singleton that can be used to get instances of IOrganizationService.